# Problems modeling the concept of "featured artists" (on rap songs)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, modeling

Sometimes rap songs have more than one artist. For example, [Nicki Minaj's "Roman's Revenge"](http://rapgenius.com/lyrics/Nicki-minaj-ft-eminem/Roman-s-revenge) features Eminem, and thus appears as "Nicki Minaj (Ft. Eminem) – Roman's Revenge" in the [Rap Genius](http://rapgenius.com) catelog.

On Rap Genius I model featured artists via a `performances` join model that has the following attributes:

- `song_id`
- `artist_id`
- `role` (either "primary" or "featured")

So:

- In `artist.rb`:

  ```
  has_many :songs, :through => :performances
  ```
- In `song.rb`:

  ```
  has_many :artists, :through => :performances
  ```

In `song.rb`:

```
def primary_artists
  performances.select{|p| p.role == 'primary'}.map(&:artist).compact
end

def featured_artists
  performances.select{|p| p.role == 'featured'}.map(&:artist).compact
end

# from the user's perspective there's only one primary artist
def primary_artist
  primary_artists.first
end
```

The question is how to implement `Song#primary_artist=` and `Song#featured_artists=`. Right now I'm doing this, which is buggy:

```
def primary_artist=(artist)
  return if artist.blank?
  Performance.song_id_eq(id).role_eq('primary').destroy_all

  performances.build(:artist => artist, :role => 'primary')
end
```

The reason this is buggy is that this method destroys all existing primary artists on the spot, but the replacement primary artist is only created when the song is saved. So, if the song save fails, it's primary artist will be deleted.

What's the right way to do this? We want the old primary artist to be removed only if the song save is successful, so one idea is:

```
def primary_artist=(artist)
  return if artist.blank?
  #Performance.song_id_eq(id).role_eq('primary').destroy_all
  @performances_to_destroy << Performance.song_id_eq(id).role_eq('primary')

  performances.build(:artist => artist, :role => 'primary')
end

def after_save
  @performances_to_destroy.each(&:destroy)
end
```

But this still seems a bit confusing / hackish.

Comment: I don't understand why you're restricting what the user sees to one primary artist.  Doesn't your problem go away if you just display all of the relevant artist(s)?

Comment: No – though I now realize the core of my question is simpler than the above. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111345/save-changes-to-a-has-many-association-only-when-you-successfully-save-the-parent

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different idea, but wouldn't it be a bit simpler and clearer to have two relationships between artists and songs here, i.e. a song would have relationships to artists along the lines of:

```
belongs_to :primary_artist,                :class_name => "Artist"
has_and_belongs_to_many :featured_artists, :class_name => "Artist"
```