# Save changes to a has_many association ONLY when you successfully save the parent object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Suppose each `Project` `has_many` `Tasks`.

If I do

```
some_project.tasks = list_of_tasks
some_project.save
```

The project's tasks get updated even if the save fails. If `list_of_tasks` consists of new records, the project's tasks get **deleted** even if the save fails! **WHOA!**

If the save fails, the project should have the same tasks it had before I started messing with it. How do I get this behavior and why isn't it the default?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Enclose the statements in a transaction:

```
Project.transaction do
  p.tasks = task_list
  p.save!
end
```

The `save!` method throws an exception upon error, which rolls back any changes done to task list.

You can read the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) if you want to dive a bit more deeply on the subject.

Comment: This works, but this approach means that whenever I update tasks across my entire application I'll have to remember to wrap it in a transaction (and I'm sure I'll forget). It would be much better if I could encapsulate this behavior in the `Project` model in a DRY fashion.

Comment: Well, define a method `replace_tasks(new_tasks)` which does just that

Answer (score 4):

You might find that the [AutosaveAssociation](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html) feature does what you want.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks, :autosave => true
end
```

This should wrap the save in a transaction automatically.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that accepts_nested_attributes_for() will provide the behavior you want:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks
end
```

This should wrap everything inside a transaction. You then need to build the form that populates the tasks accordingly. The method `tasks_attributes` in your Project model is called instead of the `tasks` method. See [the API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `#save` you can ask if `some_project#valid?` . That helps the issue if the save fails due to `some_project` being an invalid record, but is not a comprehensive solution.

As for the Rails' default behavior, it makes sense. Saying `some_project.tasks = list_of_tasks` is like saying "remove all existing tasks from some_project and assign these new ones". You are dropping the reference to the existing association Array and assigning a brand new one. This is reflected by ActiveRecord in the DB.

Comment: This DOES NOT WORK. `some_project.tasks = list_of_tasks` blows away the existing task list as soon as it's called, regardless of when or whether I call `some_project.save`. I really can't believe this is the default behavior – it's really counter-intuitive!

Comment: "Saying `some_project.tasks = list_of_tasks` is like saying "remove all existing tasks from some_project and assign these new ones"". I think it's more like saying "remove all existing tasks from `some_project` and assign these new ones *when I save `some_project`*. `some_project.name = "whatever"` doesn't take effect until I save, neither should `some_project.tasks = list_of_tasks`

Comment: @HoraceLoeb: different beast, different rules. IIRC, most ORMs follow this reasoning because it's way simpler to implement than your expected behavior (believe me, you're not the first one to come up with this). Can't really name a source, sorry.